# cannot get function metadata since there is no metadata repository

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sap-dotnet-connector

I am getting the following error + stack trace while developing a SAP server and I can't make sense of it, nor can I find any google results which provide me with any useful information:

> cannot get function metadata since there is no metadata repository

```
 at SAP.Middleware.Connector.ServerFunctionInfo.get_FunctionMetadata()
   at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcServer.InvokeServerFunction(RfcConnection conn, ServerFunctionInfo serverFuncInfo, RfcServerFunction functionImp)
   at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcServer.Dispatch(RfcConnection conn)
   at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcConnection.Dispatch()
   at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcTransaction.Playback()
   at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcServer.ARfcDestShipImp(RfcServerContext ctx, IRfcFunction func)
```

In one forum post i've come across i read that it might have to do something with permissions - but the other end said that he gave me full permissions on that test system. So that does not seem to be the reason why it isn't working.

The code is failing, as soon as the other end point attempts to send data and a server function is called on my end. This is my code:

#SAP server factory

```
public static class SapServerFactory
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, SapServer> Servers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SapServer>();

    public static SapServer Create(string configurationName)
    {
        return Servers.GetOrAdd(configurationName.ToUpper(), CreateSapServer(configurationName));
    }

    private static SapServer CreateSapServer(string configurationName)
    {
        var server = RfcServerManager.GetServer(configurationName, new Type[] { typeof(RfcServerDelegate) });
            
        return new SapServer(server);
    }
}
```

#Server delegate

```
// http://www.dataxstream.com/2011/08/nco-3-rfc-server-step-by-step/
public static class RfcServerDelegate
{
    public static event SapServerExecutionHandler ServerCalled;

    public delegate void SapServerExecutionHandler(RfcServerContext context, IRfcFunction function);

    [RfcServerFunction(Default = true)]
    public static void DefaultHandler(RfcServerContext context, IRfcFunction function)
    {
        ServerCalled?.Invoke(context, function);
    }
}
```

#SAP Server

```
public delegate void RfcServerHandler<T>(RfcServer server, T args);
public delegate void RfcServerFunctionHandler(RfcServer server, RfcServerContext context, IRfcFunction function);
public delegate void RfcTransactionIdHandler(RfcServerContextInfo context, RfcTID transactionId);
public delegate T RfcTransactionIdHandler<T>(RfcServerContextInfo context, RfcTID transactionId);

public class SapServer : IDisposable, ITransactionIDHandler
{
    public RfcServer Server { get; }

    public event RfcServerHandler<RfcServerState> StateChanged;
    public event RfcServerHandler<RfcServerErrorEventArgs> ApplicationError;
    public event RfcServerHandler<RfcServerErrorEventArgs> Error;
    public event RfcServerFunctionHandler FunctionCalled;

    public event RfcTransactionIdHandler<bool> CheckTransactionId;
    public event RfcTransactionIdHandler CommitTransactionId;
    public event RfcTransactionIdHandler ConfirmTransactionId;
    public event RfcTransactionIdHandler RollbackTransactionId;

    public SapServer(RfcServer server)
    {
        RfcServerDelegate.ServerCalled += RfcServerDelegateOnServerCalled;
        Server = server;
        Server.RfcServerStateChanged += ServerOnRfcServerStateChanged;
        Server.RfcServerApplicationError += ServerOnRfcServerApplicationError;
        Server.RfcServerError += ServerOnRfcServerError;
        Server.TransactionIDHandler = CreateDefaultTransactionHandler();
    }

    protected virtual ITransactionIDHandler GetDefaultTransactionHandler()
    {
        return this;
    }

    private ITransactionIDHandler CreateDefaultTransactionHandler()
    {
        return GetDefaultTransactionHandler();
    }

    private void RfcServerDelegateOnServerCalled(RfcServerContext context, IRfcFunction function)
    {
        if(context.Server == Server)
            FunctionCalled?.Invoke(Server, context, function);
    }

    private void ServerOnRfcServerError(object o, RfcServerErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        Error?.Invoke(o as RfcServer, args);
    }

    private void ServerOnRfcServerApplicationError(object o, RfcServerErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        ApplicationError?.Invoke(o as RfcServer, args);
    }

    private void ServerOnRfcServerStateChanged(object o, RfcServerStateChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        State = args.NewState;
        StateChanged?.Invoke(o as RfcServer, args.NewState);
    }

    public RfcServerState State { get; set; }

    private bool _firstStart = true;
    public void Start()
    {
        if (!State.In(RfcServerState.Starting, RfcServerState.Running) || _firstStart)
        {
            Server.Start();
            _firstStart = false;
        }
    }

    public void Stop(bool abortRunningCalls)
    {
        if (!State.In(RfcServerState.Stopped, RfcServerState.Stopping))
            Server.Shutdown(abortRunningCalls);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        RfcServerDelegate.ServerCalled -= RfcServerDelegateOnServerCalled;
        Server.RfcServerStateChanged -= ServerOnRfcServerStateChanged;
        Server.RfcServerApplicationError -= ServerOnRfcServerApplicationError;
        Server.RfcServerError -= ServerOnRfcServerError;

        if(Server.TransactionIDHandler is IDisposable disposableTransactionHandler && !object.ReferenceEquals(disposableTransactionHandler, this))
        {
            disposableTransactionHandler.Dispose();
        }

        Server.TransactionIDHandler = null;
    }

    bool ITransactionIDHandler.CheckTransactionID(RfcServerContextInfo ctx, RfcTID tid)
    {
        if (CheckTransactionId == null)
            return true;

        foreach (var item in CheckTransactionId.GetInvocationList())
        {
            if (item is RfcTransactionIdHandler<bool> handler)
            {
                if (!handler.Invoke(ctx, tid))
                    return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    void ITransactionIDHandler.Commit(RfcServerContextInfo ctx, RfcTID tid)
    {
        CommitTransactionId?.Invoke(ctx, tid);
    }

    void ITransactionIDHandler.Rollback(RfcServerContextInfo ctx, RfcTID tid)
    {
        RollbackTransactionId?.Invoke(ctx, tid);
    }

    void ITransactionIDHandler.ConfirmTransactionID(RfcServerContextInfo ctx, RfcTID tid)
    {
        ConfirmTransactionId?.Invoke(ctx, tid);
    }
}
```

app.config

```
<SAP.Middleware.Connector>
    <ServerSettings>
        <ServerConfiguration>
            <servers>
                <add NAME="somename" 
                     GWHOST="some.domain.com" 
                     GWSERV="somepassword"
                     PROGRAM_ID="someprogramid"
                     REG_COUNT="1" />
    </servers>
  </ServerConfiguration>
</ServerSettings>
<ClientSettings>
  <DestinationConfiguration>
    <destinations>
      <add NAME="SapDestination1"
                     SYSNR="42"
                     USER="someuser"
                     PASSWD="somepassword"
                     LANG="EN" 
                     CLIENT="011" 
                     ASHOST="somehostname"  />
            </destinations>
        </DestinationConfiguration>
    </ClientSettings>
</SAP.Middleware.Connector>
```

If this error message rings a bell to anyone: please share your insights on how to resolve it please.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was hidden in inner exceptions - The server entry requires "REPOSITORY_DESTINATION" and the login details were incorrect.